# Java Spring Framework - Principal Null on REST calls

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Java Spring Security and I am unable to set the principal after REST call with principal. I need to set the principal against the HasRole check for every endpoint, but unfortunately the principal is null during stateless calls. How can I set the principal to validate the various roles?

Comment: what do you mean by "stateless" calls? no call is stateless internally in fact REST implies State Transfer. maybe this is the answer you need? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29685203/206466

Comment: @xenoterracide maybe he means the session-managment policy set to stateless, but this is just a guess. A bit more code, especially the `UserDetailsService`, the `AuthenticationProvider` as well as the overall SpringSecurity config and a short sample of the role-usage would be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure your Provider is setting the Authentication object correctly in every request?

Comment: Apologies for the misleading question. I cannot seem to be able to pass the principal argument with every request. As a result, i am not able to have direct access to it. I am only able to get it during login like this:

request.getAttribure(principal)

The principal does not persist during api calls. However, it comes automatically during the login process.

Comment: It is still unclear how you have defined your spring security in case of REST calls. Usually you have something like `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/...").authenticated().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disabled();` to configure SpringSecurity for REST. Here, the user is authenticated via the `Authorization` HTTP Header field contained within the request, which if available results in a lookup of the user via the `UserDetailsService`